# What statistical test should I use for variable which has all values identical and zero?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, zero-inflation

I'm a neuroscientist and I count protein aggregates in the brain. I use tissue from MND patients with and without a certain mutation, and from healthy controls (3 groups in total). When I use healthy control tissue I don't usually find any aggregates, which makes some of my control data groups have zero values for all the cases. I obviously can't test these groups of data for normality.

What kinds of tests should I use for this? I'd like to test for homoscedasticity and for differences between the groups (and subsequent post hoc tests).

Comment: It's better to use a generalized linear model (zero-inflated Possion model etc), since your response is count data.

Comment: @Zhanxiong, I was just about to suggest that.  I love Diane Lambert's work there for production processes, but was thinking myself creative for applying it to medicine.  I like the idea that zero failures can still be informative.